# Multiples aliases for one command

Tags: alias

I need to have multiple aliases for one command. I've done it like that:

```
alias lwbc='$(npm bin)/webpack'
alias lwpc=lwbc
```

Is this a correct way?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @SauceCode, sure, it works

Comment: Great. But then you need to clarify what you mean when you ask if it's correct.

Comment: @SauceCode, optimal way maybe

Comment: To state the obvious, if you later decide to change the command executed by the `lwbc` alias, it will also affect what the `lwpc` alias does. If that is what you intend, then your alias is fine.

Comment: @SauceCode, okay, thanks, the following is invalid syntax, correct? `alias lwbc=lwpc='$(npm bin)/webpack'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use brace expansion.

`alias {name1,name2}="echo hello"`

or for your example

`alias lw{p,b}c="$(npm bin)/webpack"`

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html